# Centos - .htaccess file not working

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

I have just setup a new server with Centos 6 added a virtual site then tried to add an .htaccess file to run PHP in .html extensions (copied from another working setup) but the command is being ignored. I have tried adding error redirects to the access file and they are also ignored.

The contents of the access file is:

```
IndexIgnore *

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 


RemoveHandler .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html


LimitRequestBody 0
```

And this is in my httpd.conf file

```
<Directory  /home/newsite/public_html>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride All

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I've searched online and can't find anything else I might need to do.

At the moment the PHP in the HTML file is just being outputted as normal HTML.

Comment: Is .htaccess readable by the apache user?

Comment: I've already set permissions to 775

Comment: If you have full server control (not a shared environment) it's better practice to put virtual host directives in a separate file like /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ , leave httpd.conf (apache2.conf) for general directives and don't use .htaccess files. In your case you can just try to move the .htaccess directives to your httpd.conf and see if it works. Check also the apache error log after this if it doesn't work.

Comment: It turns out the htaccess file is working put the MIME directives for PHP still aren't.

Comment: I've putting the MIME directives in the conf file and it made no difference

Comment: Problem soved, it was parsing the file starting with <? it needed to be <?php